# about python scripting

Tags: python, oop

I have this code

```
 class HNCS (ThreadingTCPServer):

    def verify_request(self, request, client_address):

        for key in connections:

            if connections[key].client_address[0] == client_address[0]:

                if client_address[0] != '127.0.0.1':

                    return False

        return True

    def welcome(self):

        return '''______________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------
%s
______________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------
* Server started %s
* Waiting for connections on port %i
''' % (gpl, ctime(), PORT)
```

I only can't figure out the line where it says
if connections[key].client_address[0] == client_address[0]

how come we used client_address as an attribute after dictionary???

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the dictionary is storing values which are objects that happen to have a client_address member property?

In other words, the `.client_address` there *isn't* the same thing as the `client_address` passed in as an argument. Instead, it's the name of a field within a class that happens to be stored in `connections[key]`.

Comment: don't bother ur self, got :D
thnx dude

Comment: another question, 
what happens when I say inside a class
test[self.name]=self
does this mean that the object itself with its attributes is stored in the list with the name give???

Comment: A reference to the object is, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `connections` dictionary may have an object with a `client_address` attribute?

Like:

```
class SomeClass(object):
     def __init__( self, address ) :
          self.client_address = address

connections = {"oscar":SomeClass(["127.0.0.1","192.60.0.1"])}

for key in connections:
    print connections[key].client_address[0]
```

**edit**

A `dict` is a dictionary where a value may be stored using a key. When you request that key again, you get the value back, is that simple.

So in my previous example, the line:

```
connections = {"oscar":SomeClass(["127.0.0.1","192.60.0.1"])}
```

Could have been written as:

```
connection = []
connections["oscar"] = SomeClass(["1","2"])
s = connections["oscar"]
```

In your comment `test[self.name] = self` your storing the object represented by `self` into the `test` dictionary using `name` as the key.

Comment: another question, 
what happens when I say inside a class
test[self.name]=self
does this mean that the object itself with its attributes is stored in the list with the name give???

Answer (score 1):

```
    for key in connections:
        if connections[key].client_address[0] == client_address[0]:
```

This is simply looking at all the values stored in the `connections` dictionary, to see if any of their properties named `client_address` have the same first item (IP address) as the local variable `client_address`. It's not necessary for the variable to have the same name as the property of the value in the dictionary.

What it's saying is: abort the connection if another connection from the same IP address is already being served. (Except for localhost, which is allowed to have as many connections as it likes.)

It could be re-spelled as:

```
def verify_request(self, request, new_client_addr):
    ip= new_client_addr[0]
    active_ips= [value.client_address[0] for value in connections.values()]
    return ip not in active_ips or ip=='127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: @kmitnick: There is no function overloading in Python.